# Using Regex to modify a String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a String that looks like this:

```
Blah blah one.<tmp>[[url=b, link=c]]</tmp> Blah blah two.
Also remember, blah blah three.<tmp>[[url=d, link=e]]</tmp>
```

So I want to get `b` and `d` (the `url` attribute of `tmp`), and change the String so that it looks like this (the `ex()` function returns a String):

```
Blah blah one.<tmp>[[url=b, link=c, add=ex(b)]]</tmp> Blah blah two.
Also remember, blah blah three.<tmp>[[url=d, link=e, add=ex(d)]]</tmp>
```

I need to use regex because no existing library parses this type of markup.

I hope my explanation is clear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) 2. This begs for a full-blown parser, not a regex.

Comment: Sorry for the unnecessary edit. I changed the code-quote to block quote and didn't notice that the tags was invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var text = "Blah blah one.<tmp>[[url=b, link=c]]</tmp> Blah blah two.";
text.replace(/(url=([^,]+), [^\]]+)/g, "$1, add=ex($2)");

// return "Blah blah one.<tmp>[[url=b, link=c, add=ex(b)]]</tmp> Blah blah two."
```

UPDATE:

```
// declare your ex() function first
var text = "Blah blah one.<tmp>[[url=b, link=c]]</tmp> Blah blah two.";
text.replace(/(url=([^,]+), [^\]]+)/g, function(){ 
    return RegExp.$1 +", add="+ex(RegExp.$2)+""; 
});
```

Comment: Ok, so far it's working for me in that `add=ex(b)` is added to the String, but `ex()` is a function. How do I pass `b` into it and then use the returned value to do `add=returnedValue`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var str = "Blah blah one.<tmp>[[url=http://www.google.com, link=c]]</tmp> Blah blah two.";
var tempRe = /(<tmp>\[\[url=)([^,]+)(link=[^\]]\])(, \]<\/tmp>)/;

var newStr = str.replace(tempRe, '$1$2$3,add=ex($2)$4');
```

This replaces only strings inside `<tmp></tmp>`.

Comment: I guess his ex function returns a string